# How to smooth extremely dense mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have an imported model (which actually is a surface projection of an microscope Z-stack image, exported as STL) which is extremely grainy, composed of almost 1M verts. Is there any way to reduce number of verts/faces and smooth it to recover the general cell shape? I tried smooth and remesh modifiers, but it didn't help a lot :( 
Thanks for any ideas!
Art.

[image]

Comment: Use MeshLab for this kind of work. It's free. Blender is not the right tool.

Comment: try the decimate modifier

Comment: I would try to export a less detailed model to begin with - might be much easier this way

Comment: Try shrink wrapping a simpler geometry to the object.

Answer (score -1):

Try scaling it on the Z axis to 0 in edit mode to get rid of all the bumps if thats what you are asking. [image: Scaled to zero in edit mode]

Comment: Note that this will not minimize amount of geometry and resources required to handle with it, rather create quite a bit of overlapping faces even in your example and a horrible mess of overlaps in the OP's example.